# Installing Source Packages

Tags: r

I'm unable to install certain source packages in R. Until now I've just made do with using binary, however the in trying to use rmarkdown this workaround isn't possible (RMarkdown requires updated version to work).

I don't understand what this issue is. I've installed the correct version of RTools (3.5) for the R (3.6.3) that I'm using, but that alone hasn't fixed it.
Am using Windows 10.

Would really appreciate pointing in the right direction. The error message looks like this (for all packages that fail):

```
** Installing R Package Dependencies for R Markdown: 'rmarkdown', 'stringi'


[1/4] Installing bslib...

Installing package into 'C:/Users/paulb/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependency 'htmltools'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
htmltools 0.5.1.1  0.5.2              TRUE
bslib       0.2.4  0.3.1             FALSE

installing the source packages 'htmltools', 'bslib'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/htmltools_0.5.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 124510 bytes (121 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 121 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bslib_0.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4908277 bytes (4.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.7 MB

Error: object 'R' not found
Execution halted
```

Comment: See the instructions for how to instal rtools at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ . (ps R version 3.6 is 3 years old, if you can its is worth upgrading and then installing the latest rtools)

Comment: ... you may also want to avoid installing the packages on OneDrive

Answer (score -1):

First we have to install r version and RStudio  then install recommend packages.
Use below youtube  link in Hindi.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgmCiZvdI_4